# Add administrative level

Tags: python, python-3.x, openstreetmap, osmnx

I just discovered osmnx and I'm still exploring all its features. All I can say for now is that it's an amazing package !

I looked at your code

```
places = ox.gdf_from_places(['Botswana', 'Zambia', 'Zimbabwe'])
places = ox.project_gdf(places)
ox.save_gdf_shapefile(places)
ox.plot_shape(ox.project_gdf(places))
```

Is there a way to have the admisitrative level 2 for example?
Thanks,
Jaber

Answer (score 0):

OSMnx will attempt to geocode any place name you provide it, including nations, states, counties, cities, etc using the Nominatim API. You can provide the string directly, or break it out into an explicit dict as explained in the documentation.